# nav bar wrapping when it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a nav bar with width 1000px with 4 250px wide links within it. I also have set padding and margin of all the elements to 0. But for some reason the elements still wrap onto another line, when I lower the width to 247px or less they are all displayed on the same line but they wrap on 248 or more. This is the css I have:

```
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container
{
    border: 1px solid;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 1000px;

    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

.menu-container
{
    min-height:60px;
}

nav a, a:link, a:visited
{
    color: #000000;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: ###px;
    text-align: center;
}

nav a:hover
{
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

When ### is 247 or less they all display on one line, when it is 248 or more they wrap.

And here is the html I have:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="menu-container">
    <nav>
      <a href="/">Home</a>
      <a href="/games">Games</a>
      <a href="/tags">Tags</a>
      <a href="/scores">Scores</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

I really want them to be 250px wide each so that they take up the whole width of the nav bar (setting them to 247px doesn't take up the whole nav bar) but I do not want them to wrap. Does anyone have any idea what the issue is?

Comment: what do you mean by 'wrap'?

Comment: Wrap means to be automatically put on the next line if the line is too long

Comment: Yeah that is what I meant, I couldn't think of a better word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `inline-block` whitespace will be considered

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="menu-container">
    <nav>
      <a href="/">Home</a><!-- white space here -->
      <a href="/games">Games</a><!-- white space here -->
      <a href="/tags">Tags</a><!-- white space here -->
      <a href="/scores">Scores</a><!-- white space here -->
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

One simple fix would be

```
<nav>
  <a href="/">Home</a><a href="/games">Games</a><a href="/tags">Tags</a><a href="/scores">Scores</a>
</nav>
```

You can as well think of improving your HTML. As you are trying to display a **list of links** used for navigation, consider using `ul` and `li`

**Update**

Some typical cases

**[Apple](http://www.apple.com)**

```
ul {
display: table;
width: 845px;
table-layout: fixed;
}

li {
display: table-cell;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}

a{
display;block
}
```

**[Yahoo](http://yahoo.com)**

```
ul{
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
}
li {
display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Don't you mean `<!-- white space here -->`? :)

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist TY, been coding JS for a while

Comment: That worked perfectly thank you!! Also as a side question is there any difference between a <nav> and a <div> in terms of how it is displayed / how it works or is it just to indicate a navigation block?

Comment: Actually putting it into a list still didn't stop it from including the whitespace between <li> elements for some reason. So I had to put the closing </li> and the opening <li> of the next list element on the same line which is really annoying.

Comment: @semicolon I suggested that only to keep your code semantic, the same reason why you used `nav` for navigation, `inline-block` when applied to any element would show same behavior`

Comment: @semicoon `nav` and `div` have same default presentation. The difference is in semantics they imply.

Comment: Ah I see, how do people typically make navigation bars to avoid issues such as this? `block` + `float left` ?

Comment: Let me add some typical cases to answer.